# KML and altitude

Tags: kml, cesiumjs

I have the following KML file which is a cube =>

```
</Placemark>
<Style id="3Dobject">
    <PolyStyle>
        <color>7fff5500</color>
        <outline>1</outline>
        <fill>1</fill>
    </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Placemark>
    <name>Warehouse01</name>
    <description>Warehouse Center：106.97777777 -6.19758333</description>
    <styleUrl>#3Dobject</styleUrl>
    <Polygon>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
                <coordinates>
                    106.9772778,-6.19808333,100
                    106.9782778,-6.19808333,100
                    106.9782778,-6.19708333,100
                    106.9772778,-6.19708333,100
                    106.9772778,-6.19808333,100
                </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
</Placemark>
```

I am trying to make this cube to be drawn 100meters above the ground. (

so basically =>

[image]

I tried adding an 100 but it always display from the botom.

I am using CESIUM.

Comment: Does it need to be KML?  That sort of thing is much easier with CZML.

Comment: The client can only provide me KML at the moment.

Comment: In KML draw the faces of the cube with extrude turned off. UPDATE: Or can in KML also use a COLLADA model of a generic cube with a location 100 meters above ground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1: MultiGeometry with 6 polygons**

By definition [extrude](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#polygon) makes a geometry in KML connect to the ground. To create a 3-D cube above the ground then you must turn off extude and represent a polygon for each of the 6 faces of the cube.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">

<Placemark>
  <name>Altitude PolyCube Example</name>
  <Style>
    <PolyStyle>
        <color>7fffffff</color>
    </PolyStyle>
  </Style>
  <MultiGeometry>
    <Polygon>
      <!-- bottom panel -->
      <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
      <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
          <coordinates>
     106.9772778,-6.19808333,100
     106.9782778,-6.19808333,100
     106.9782778,-6.19708333,100
     106.9772778,-6.19708333,100
     106.9772778,-6.19808333,100
          </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>

    <Polygon>
      <!-- top panel -->
      <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
      <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
          <coordinates>
     106.9772778,-6.19808333,200
     106.9782778,-6.19808333,200
     106.9782778,-6.19708333,200
     106.9772778,-6.19708333,200
     106.9772778,-6.19808333,200
          </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>

    <Polygon>
      <!-- left panel -->
      <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
      <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
          <coordinates>
     106.9772778,-6.19808333,100
     106.9772778,-6.19808333,200
     106.9772778,-6.19708333,200
     106.9772778,-6.19708333,100
     106.9772778,-6.19808333,100
          </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>

    <Polygon>
      <!-- right panel -->
      <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
      <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
          <coordinates>
    106.9782778,-6.19808333,100
    106.9782778,-6.19808333,200
    106.9782778,-6.19708333,200
    106.9782778,-6.19708333,100
    106.9782778,-6.19808333,100
          </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>

    <Polygon>
      <!-- front panel -->
      <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
      <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
          <coordinates>
     106.9772778,-6.19808333,100
     106.9782778,-6.19808333,100
     106.9782778,-6.19808333,200
     106.9772778,-6.19808333,200
     106.9772778,-6.19808333,100
          </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>

    <Polygon>
      <!-- back panel -->
      <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
      <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
          <coordinates>
     106.9772778,-6.19708333,100
     106.9782778,-6.19708333,100
     106.9782778,-6.19708333,200
     106.9772778,-6.19708333,200
     106.9772778,-6.19708333,100
          </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>

  </MultiGeometry>
</Placemark>

</kml>
```

**Option 2: KML and COLLADA Cube Model**

Given a generic cube model (which you can download at the [3D Warehouse](https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/)), the KML can place a cube at a given location including at an altitude above ground.

**Option 3: Cesium**

Cesium using a Box geometry so can simply place a Box at a given altitude of 100 meters. For example see [Cesium Sandcastle Box Demo](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Box.html).